# Program Cost as a function of the size of the input

Tags: algorithm, computation-theory

```
    public static int[] cip(int[] v, int n)
    {
        if (n < v.length) return cucu(v);
        v = ciop(v);
        v = ciop(v);
        return cip(v, n);
    }

    private static int[] ciop(int[] v) {    
        int[] w = new int[2*v.length];
        int i = O, j = v.length - 1, k = O;
        whi1e(i < v.length) {
            w[k++] = v[i++];
            w[k++] = v[j--1];
        }
        return w;
    }

    private static int[] cucu(int[] v)
    {
        int[] w = new int[1];
        w[O] = cucu(v, O);
        return w;
    }

    private static int cucu(int[] v, int i)
    {
        if (i >= v.length) return O;
        int r = O;
        if (i < v.length) r += v[i];
        return r + cucu(v, i + 1);
    }
```

(a) Calculate the computational cost of the `cip(int[] v, int n)` method according to the dimension of the array `v` and the value `n`.

(b) Express the cost calculated in the previous step as a function of the size of the input.

This is an exercise that my professor gave in the classroom, but I have many doubts. As must be done in general to calculate the computational cost of an algorithm as a function of the size of the input? I have set the input? Or do I get the input from the methods that are provided to me? Does "computational cost" mean "cost in terms of time" or "cost in terms of space and time"?

Comment: We don't know what your prof means by 'cost', either or both of 'cost in time' and 'cost in space' would be sensible.  Since neither is particularly difficult to compute for your examples, go for both, you'll learn twice as much. Now, step away from the keyboard.  Take small sample inputs to your functions and count, on your fingers and toes (or even with pencil and paper) how many basic operations (+,-,*,/) the functions require.  Do this for a few small inputs until you get a feel for the impact that the inputs have on the number of operations.  Do the same for the amount of space ...

Comment: "Cost" is usually meant to be "cost in time" if not explicitly specified.

Comment: in http://cr.yp.to/nfscircuit/dollarseconds.html the cost of a computation is defined as the product of the time taken by the computation and the cost of the hardware used for the computation. There are **many** possible meaning of the term. We are not the students of your professor. What do you mean?

Comment: @Gangnus - Please do not add homework tag to posts, it's Obsolete and in the process of being removed.

Comment: @Mike So, homework questions are allowed and not marked anymore? Where could I get some link to the changed rules, please?

Comment: Also, make sure to add `#define O 0` somewhere at the beginning, it will hardly compile without it.

Comment: @Gangnus - [meta faq, see first answer regarding the tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), also [homework tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info) provides another link about the clean up.